# socket.io query parameter not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have this code:

```
var ss = io('/secure', { query: 'token='+string });
```

It used to pass the query parameter to the server that was accessible as socket.handshake.query with this code:

```
io.of('/secure').use(function(socket, next){
    // ***
    console.log( socket.handshake.query );


    // validate token

    next();
});
```

but now it is not working and the output of the console.log does not include the token property:

```
{ EIO: '3', transport: 'polling', t: '1410465157747-0' }
```

I also tried changing my syntax to syntax that I have seen elsewhere online...

```
var ss = io('/secure', { query: { 'token': string } });
```

and this does not add the query property to socket.handshake.query either...

Please help!

btw I am using socket.io 1.1.0

Comment: I've been having some issues lately due to some changes they are making. Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using 1.1.0 but noticed this issue at 1.0.6

Comment: I remember that they changed query for _query a while, but that's not the problem here. I think you should take a look at the GitHub repo issues and open one in case that there is nothing like this.

Comment: I just checked the issues for socket.io-client and found an old issue/bug that is the problem for me https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/issues/331 this means that query parameters are not sent for second io connection on a website

Comment: I have the same issue, but interestingly, it only occurs when I use port 8080. When I test it at port 1337, it sends the query data at the second try and connects without problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am on socket.io latest version (v 1.3.6) and found the same issue - for second connection, the `query` is not being sent.

I use socket.io for two purposes, chat and notification. Both were running on same port. Since these were two separate services, I started two separate servers on different ports - one for each service. Since then the issue has not been seen.

***Try this: So if you have more than one service, try separating them into different ports.***

```
var http_nfy = require('http').Server(app).listen(6001);    
var io_nfy = require('socket.io')(http_nfy);
var http_cht = require('http').Server(app).listen(6002);    
var io_cht = require('socket.io')(http_cht);
```

Then I used these two `io` differently:

```
io_nfy.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
var chatNsp = io_cht.of('/chat');
```

I am not sure if this is a bug or intended behaviour, hence did not open an issue. If someone can confirm that this is a bug, I would be happy to report and keep track of that bug.